# how can I install vicon_bridge?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and ros indigo and I am a new user.  When I run "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-vicon-bridge" in command line to install the vicon_bridge package it says "unable to locate package".  I have tried some variations on that command but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong and I can't seem to find any instruction.  Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233177/how-can-i-install-vicon_bridge?/) by [iopollycron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26731/iopollycron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at the [vicon_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/vicon_bridge) wiki page, you'll notice the only green status indicator at the top is "Documented" --- there is no "Released" or "Continuous integration" as compared to, for example, [camera_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration). This was my first indication that this package isn't released on Indigo. I then checked `apt-cache search vicon` to verify that the package isn't available on `apt-get` (which is exactly what your error says). So the basic problem is the package you want to install has not been released to the ROS build farm. Thus, you can't install a pre-built binary from `apt-get`. So, we need to build this package from source:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
git clone https://github.com/ethz-asl/vicon_bridge
rosdep install -r --from-paths vicon_bridge/
cd ~/catkin_ws/
catkin_make
```

Those commands will clone the package into your workspace (you may need to adjust the path), verify you have system dependencies installed, and then compile the package in your workspace. Now you should be able to run and launch nodes in this package (assuming you've sourced your workspace's setup.bash).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EduardoCota](https://answers.ros.org/users/30275/eduardocota/) on 2017-05-05**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [Patricia2602](https://answers.ros.org/users/61733/patricia2602/) on 2020-12-28**:
I followed these instructions but bumped into these errors after running `catkin_make`

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/patricia/catkin_ws/src/vicon_bridge/vicon_sdk/Vicon_SDK_1.3_Linux/64-bit/libViconDataStreamSDK_CPP.so when searching for -lViconDataStreamSDK_CPP
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lViconDataStreamSDK_CPP
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
vicon_bridge/CMakeFiles/testclient.dir/build.make:101: recipe for target '/home/patricia/catkin_ws/devel/lib/vicon_bridge/testclient' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/patricia/catkin_ws/devel/lib/vicon_bridge/testclient] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4212: recipe for target 'vicon_bridge/CMakeFiles/testclient.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [vicon_bridge/CMakeFiles/testclient.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 28%] Built target crs_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 34%] Built target crs_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 40%] Built target crs_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
```

**Comment by [Patricia2602](https://answers.ros.org/users/61733/patricia2602/) on 2020-12-28**:
ok I figured out that it's not compatible with arm architecture (I'm using NVIDIA Jetson Nano)